# SELECT an array of data from a table in the order I need

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Let 's imagine such a table

```
create table test
(
    main_id   uuid,
    first_id uuid,
    second_id uuid
);
```

there are such ids

```
           main_id                           first_id                 second_id

"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000011"       "...11"                    "...11"
           "...12"                           "...12"                    "...12"
           "...13"                           "...13"                    "...13"
```

i have a query

```
SELECT main_id
FROM test
WHERE (first_id, second_id) IN (SELECT UNNEST(@first_ids::uuid[]), UNNEST(@second_ids::uuid[]));
```

i'm sending `first_ids = ("...13", "...11", "...12")`, `second_ids = ("...13", "...11", "...12")`

Expected: `main_id = ("...13", "...11", "...12")`

Actual: I get the result in random order (in the same order as in the database)

Comment: ORDER BY
 main_id ASC; ?

Comment: @antokhio the order may be random. And we're talking about uuids. I need to continue working with the returned values. I need to understand the order in which they returned. To correlate first_id, second_id with main_id.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```sql
SELECT (
SELECT main_id
FROM test
WHERE first_id = @first_ids[i]::uuid
AND
second_id = @second_ids[i]::uuid
)
FROM
generate_series(1,cardinality(@first_ids)) i
ORDER BY i
```

I don't know if my casting there is right, and I'm not sure if the `ORDER BY` is actually necessary when you're using generate_series, but the idea here is to map over your arrays using `[i]` so that you can keep your place.